# java adding 2 xml documents together

Tags: java, xml, domdocument

I have two seperate java Document objects:

Doc1 :

```
       <CIS_REQUEST>
           <Request1>
       </CIS_REQUEST>
       <CIS_RESPONSE>
            <RESPONSE1>
            <RESPONSE2>
       </CIS_RESPONSE>
```

Doc2 :

```
        <CIS_REQUEST>
            <Request1>
        </CIS_REQUEST>
```

I want the resulting document to look like:

```
 <CIS_REQUEST>
       <Request1>
   </CIS_REQUEST>
   <CIS_RESPONSE>
        <RESPONSE1>
        <RESPONSE2>
   </CIS_RESPONSE>
   <PROCESSING>1</PROCESSING>
   <CIS_PROFILES>
      <CIS_REQUEST>
        <Request1>
      </CIS_REQUEST>
   <CIS_PROFILES>
```

The code I have so far:

```
 Document doc2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument(combinedResponse);
 counter++;
                String counter_str = Integer.toString(counter);
                Element count = doc2.createElement("PROCESSING");
                root.appendChild(count);
                Text counter_text = doc2.createTextNode(counter_str);
                count.appendChild(counter_text);
  Element profileElement = doc2.createElement(profName + "_profiles");
  profileElement.append(doc1)  //I need some replacement for this code.
```

Can anyone educate me on how I can just append one document to another, and not insert it somewhere in the original document?

Comment: The output is not a valid XML document as it has multiple root elements.  Also, the `<CIS_PROFILES>` section does not occur in the input. Where did it come from? If all you want to do is concatenate the files you don't need a Java program.

Comment: I don't have 2 xml files, I am trying to avoid converting docs 2 xml and concatenating as string and transforming back to document. THe first doc object is constructed.